# Problema al poner un prefab que tiene una animación hecha con huesos, en un panel de Unity (con C#)

Tags: c#, canvas, unity, animación

Estoy haciendo un juego en Unity con C#. Cuando termina aparece un panel con un mensaje y una imagen animada con huesos que no puedo incluir (solo animaciones comunes sin huesos), si me pueden ayudar desde ya muy agradecida.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con un meshRender.

Renderiza tu animación con huesos en otra cámara, lo capturas y lo muestras en tu menú. Yo lo hago generalmente para mostrar objetos 3d en ui.

Comment: Buenas tardes Daniel, Muchas gracias por responder mi consulta. Voy a intentar aplicarlo, este es un proyecto 2D. Nuevamente gracias.